# Coin tosses probability to calculate

Tags: probability

I'm stuck at solving the following problem: launch 3 fair coins independently. Let A the event: "you get at least a head" and B "you get exactly one tail".
Then what is the probability of the event $A \cup B$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you list all the outcomes which would comprise $A\cup B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$. Now $\overline{A}$ is you get not heads and $\overline{B}$ is you get any number of tails but one. Only one option fits $\overline{A}$ and it is TTT, which fits also $\overline{B}$.

So $\Pr(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})=\tfrac{1}{2^3}$ and $\Pr(A\cap B)=1-\tfrac{1}{2^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that you want is everything except if you get all $3$ tails, since everything else is in the union of $A$ and $B$. So the answer = $1 - \frac{1}{8} = \boxed{\frac{7}{8}}$.